# Spring class level validation and Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, validation, thymeleaf

I am learning Spring Framework and Thymeleaf. I have known how to display field error by using something like `${#fields.errors("xx")}`. However, I get stuck about how to display object error message in Thymeleaf.

Here is my **UserForm** class:

```
@PasswordMatches
public class UserForm {
    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private String username;
    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private String password;
    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private String matchingPassword;
    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @ValidEmail
    private String email;

    /* setter and getter methods */
```

Here is my **PasswordMatches** annotation:

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE}) 
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = PasswordMatchesValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface PasswordMatches { 
    String message() default "Passwords don't match";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {}; 
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}

class PasswordMatchesValidator implements ConstraintValidator<PasswordMatches, Object> {  
    @Override
    public void initialize(PasswordMatches constraintAnnotation) {       
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Object obj, ConstraintValidatorContext context){   
        UserDto user = (UserDto) obj;
        return user.getPassword().equals(user.getMatchingPassword());    
  }     
}
```

Here is my **Controller** method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/registration", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView registerUserAccount(@ModelAttribute("user") @Valid UserForm userForm,
          BindingResult result, WebRequest request, Errors errors) {
    if (!result.hasErrors()) {
        return new ModelAndView("registerSuccess");
    }
    else {
        return new ModelAndView("registration", "user", userForm);
    }
}
```

Now here is my problem: If the ***password*** field and ***confirmPass*** field doesn't match, how can I get the default error message returned by the class level annotation in Thymeleaf?

Answer (score 10):

I know this is old post but I also encountered this problem and here is the soulution (maybe it will also help someone else): 
Modify PasswordMatchesValidator to this:

```
class PasswordMatchesValidator implements ConstraintValidator<PasswordMatches, Object> {  
@Override
public void initialize(PasswordMatches constraintAnnotation) {       
}

@Override
public boolean isValid(Object obj, ConstraintValidatorContext context){   
    UserDto user = (UserDto) obj;
    boolean isValid = user.getPassword().equals(user.getMatchingPassword());
    if(!isValid){
         context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
        context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(context.getDefaultConstraintMessageTemplate())
                .addPropertyNode( "matchingPassword" ).addConstraintViolation();
    }
    return isValid;
```

}

it will bind the validation result to your 'matchingPassword' attribute. So in your thymeleaf template us it like this:

```
${#fields.errors("matchingPassword")}
```

Comment: Such a rare solution. I have tried this and it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Add this inside the `form` tag:

```html
<p data-th-each="err : ${#fields.allErrors()}" data-th-text="${err}" class="error">
  Invalid input.
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. It seems that the code is to display all the binding errors. I wonder if there is some ways to specify the error generated by the class level validation.

Comment: Is there any update on this question. I am also struck on the same issue. Is there a better way to resolve this at the entity level rather than from field level?

Answer (score 0):

```
  <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('${yourObject}')}" th:errors="${yourObject}"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.